# Android: how to implement a continously zoom function

Tags: android, zooming

I am looking for a way to implement a continously zoom. With continously I mean that I want to zoom to one position and zoom from there to another and so on. Like in the browser.

My aproach so far is only capable of a one time zoom and resets before the next.

First I calculate the distance between the fingers and the mid point inbetween.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

if(mode == ZOOM) {
    float newDist = spacing(event);
    scale = newDist / oldDist;
    midPoint(midPoint, event);
    invalidate();
}
```

The method invalidate calls the onDraw where I tell the matrix to do the scaling.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    canvas.setMatrix(matrix);

    // drawing code
}
```

Is there a better cumulating aproach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want animated zooming, you must compute the animation in a Timer. This means that over time you transform from one matrix to another, invalidate view, and apply resulting matrix in onDraw.
This way ou get smooth transition from one zoom level to another.

Comment: No I don't want to have an animation. My question is about touch events. A zoom stops with one touch gesture and should go on with the next in a different spot but continue with the last zoom level like in a pdf viewer.